# xcode 8 value of type 'Error' has no member 'userinfo'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8

I just upgraded to Xcode 8 and am already getting errors which cause the build to fail. I'm very new to swift, please help.

[image]

What should I change this to? Thanks

UPDATE

Apart from this error i also got the following:

```
PFUser.logInWithUsername(inBackground: usernameTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, block: { (user, error) -> Void in

                    //self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

                    if user != nil {

                        self.launchDrawerMenu()

                    } else {

                        let convertedError = error! as NSError

                        //if let errorString = convertedError["error"] as? String {
                            errorMessage = errorString
                        }
                        self.displayAlert("Login failed", message: errorMessage)

                    }
                })
```

for the // line I got "type NSError has no subscript members" error. I tried bridging it to NSError but it does not work this time. What should i do? thanks a lot

Comment: What's the object type of `error`? Like it's an `NSError` object or some custom object?

Comment: @Asad Ali it is a NSError

Comment: It is Error not NSError

Comment: Try to use error!.localizedDescription

Comment: Try bridging it with `NSError` and check the result.

Comment: got another similar error. tried using NSError but doesn't seem to work. Please see update and help. thanks so much!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

First of all, post the code (text) rather than a screenshot.

In Swift 3 `NSError` has been replaced in many APIs with more generic Swift `Error` protocol which has no `userInfo` dictionary. Bridge cast the object to `NSError`

```
if let errorString = (error as? NSError)?.userInfo....
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I also got another similar error, please see update and help. Really appreciate it

Comment: You forgot `userInfo`, that's the property which can be subscripted.

Comment: thats very dumb of me. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found this worked

```
let errorUserInfo : NSDictionary? = ((error as Any) as! NSError).userInfo["error"] as? NSDictionary
```